# || ('OR') operator alternative

Tags: javascript

I obviously got something terribly wrong here so I'll appreciate any good 'ol advice.
How come that if I write

```
var x=''; 
var y="12345";
(y.substring(0, 3) === "000"||"999") ? x=1: x=0;

console.log (x, y.substring(0, 3));
```

The answer would be `1 "123"`
instead of     `0 "123"`?

Thanks y'all!

Comment: You probably mean `y.substring(0, 3) === "000" || y.substring(0, 3) === "999"`

Comment: It means `(y.substring(0, 3) === "000") || ("999")`, which evaluates to `false || "999"`, of which `"999"` is truthy, so the left side of the ternary is truthy and that's why you get `1` not `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The or operater works like this: `a || b`

Where each statement is isolated from eachother, basically you can make i more visible like this:

```
var c1 = y.substring(0, 3) === "000";
var c2 = "999";

if ( c1 || c2 ) { x = 1; } else { x = 0; };
```

See the problem here?

I would rewrite your statement so something like this:

```
x = ["000", "999"].indexOf(y.slice(0, 3)) > -1 ? 1 : 0;
```

Note how I'm using `Array.prototype.indexOf` to test multiply cases:

```
["000", "999"].indexOf(y.slice(0, 3)) // returns the index of the array or -1 if not in the array.
```

Comment: Great, your last example was exactly what I was looking for. I used it to test if the inserted user cell phone number starts with valid area code :
`["562" ,"310", "323","714"].indexOf($("#phone").val().slice(0, 3)) !== -1`

Answer (score 3):

First the ternary operator syntax is not how you use it normally and you'll have to make two comparisons instead of one.

```
var str = y.substring(0, 3);
x = (str === "000"|| str === "999") ? 1 : 0;
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
For `condition ? expr1 : expr2`

> If condition is true, the operator returns the value of expr1;
>   otherwise, it returns the value of expr2.

Comment: `The ternary operator syntax is wrong`: no, it's not. Clearly not the best way to do it, but definitively not wrong.